# Need to update inbetween action in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my scenario I am using ***Poll***, so I having two output text field with render option for showing data like "**Waiting for refresh**" and "**Refresh happened**" , when poll action starts I need to show "Waiting for refresh" and then I collect some data from back end ,it may take few (seconds or minutes or hour) after getting data i need to update "Refresh happened" finally poll action ends its a cycle for every 30 seconds.**how to do this** ?

```
**Viewer Java Class :**

public String pollAction()
    {
        pollCountRendered = false;


    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ViewerFormId:headerId");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ViewerFormId:ContainerId");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            pollCount++;
            System.out.println("Poll Action");
            pollCountRendered = true;
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ViewerFormId:headerId");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ViewerFormId:ContainerId");
            return null;
        }

**XHTML :**

    <p:panel id="ContainerId">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1"id="headerId"
                                     cellpadding="3"
                                     cellspacing="3">
                            <h:panelGrid id="refreshId"
                                         columns="3"
                                         title="Refresh Status"
                                         cellpadding="3"
                                         cellspacing="3"
                                         style="height: 3em;border-radius:20px;font-weight: bold;">

                                <h:outputText id="refreshInId"
                                              value="Refresh In : "
                                              style="font-size:1.6em !important;font-family:message-box;font-weight:bold;border:none;background:none;"/>

                                <h:outputText id="refreshCountId"
                                              value="Waiting for refresh" 
                                              rendered="#{Viewer.pollCountRendered}"
                                              style="text-align: center;
                                              position: relative;top: 1px;
                                              font-size: 1.6em;"/>

                                <h:outputText value="Refresh happened" 
                                              rendered="#{not Viewer.pollCountRendered}"
                                              style="text-align: center;
                                              position: relative;top: 1px;
                                              font-size: 1.6em;"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGrid>

    <div>
                    <h:form>
                        <p:poll id="pollId" widgetVar="pollId"  
                                interval="30" 

                                autoStart="#{Viewer.pollStart}"
                                stop="#{Viewer.pollStop}"
                                listener="#{Viewer.pollAction}"
                                update="@([id$=pollId]),@([id$=headerId])" >
                        </p:poll>
                        </div>

</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Question need more explanation to us. Let me try to give answer. follow this link [Primeface Pool](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml).

in code you can update the panel `<p:panel id="ContainerId">` in `update="ContainerId"`. You can increase your interval by `interval="3"`.

This poll will update your panel and your panel will display latest value, and output component with render according.

Note: Tag your question with "JSF" so more user can view your question.